# Anonymous class with MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools, anonymous-class

Can I create the anonymous class(java term) using the MooTools js framework?
Suppose it should look like:

```
A = new Class({
  invoke: function() {
    alert('class');
  } 
});

a = new A({
  invoke: function() {
    this.parent();
    alert('instance');
  },
});
```

But I don't want to modify constructor interface around to accept additional properties.
Is there more comfortable way to define classes that are used not more than once?

Answer (score 1):

You could define the class only within the scope it is going to be used in, which means the class won't be available outside that scope. For example, using a self-executing function:

```
(function() {

    var MyClass = new Class({
      invoke: function() {
        alert('class');
      } 
    });

    var myObject = new MyClass({
      invoke: function() {
        this.parent();
        alert('instance');
      }
    });

})();
```

(I've fixed up several errors in your code, including omitting the `var` keyword when declaring `MyClass` and `myObject`, and an extra `,` when initialising `myObject`.)